# D7000 HD video format - can each frame contain metadata?

Tags: video

In fact the question is the other way round:

I shoot a HD video with my Nikon-D7000, and along the way things happen, such as I change zoom, focal length, light levels change such that the D7000 adjusts its sensitivity during the recording...

Is all this data available for reading somewhere, and if yes how?

I could not find the information on regular websites (Nikon's, www.imaging-resource.com, general google search).

I tried exiftool, but it seems to only show general metadata that is true for the overall video recording.

So is this data recorded somewhere, and can I read it on my Linux system?

Any answer or hint appreciated.

Comment: Can't answer your question, but I've done some analysis of Canon MOV files and have concluded that they do not store real time changes to EXIF metadata, they store a single EXIF block similar to what goes into a RAW or JPEG file.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, sounds like I might be out of luck, as it seems to me that since they already use exif, it would be the best vehicle for that sort of data.

Comment: Again, not the answer you are looking for, but for Canon shooters the Magic Lantern open source firmware has a "movie logging" option. This writes a .LOG file alongside the .MOV that includes lens and exposure changes throughout the movie with timestamps. Pretty cool.

Comment: @Miguel, wow, I wish I had something like this for my Nikon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** Standard video formats do not work like that and the D7000 is no exception to this.  Conceivably it can be done but I am sure it is not on anyone's priority list. I worked for 9 years on video processing and rendering software and there are more important problems to solve. Indexing and managing that data would also become a problem. When working on functions that process video from a series of still images, it makes it vastly simpler to assume the metadata of the first frame applies to all subsequent ones.

Obviously I understand why it would be desirable but this is the same on all cameras. GPS is another perfect example. On cameras with built-in GPS, only the location of at the time video recording starts is recorded while you may be shooting from a moving vehicle and cover some ground while recording.

Comment: H.264 standard allows inclusion per-frame metadata and it's used for in video streams of security cameras. But I agree with Itai in that it's probably not one of the top wanted features.

Comment: Interesting. I've worked on video for TV and Films, so I didn't know about the use in  security cameras. What per-frame data do the use?

Comment: You mean what's in the payload? Things like motion detection info, relay input states, tampering detection and so on.

Comment: @Itai, thanks. Not the answer I wished to have read, but informative and to the point.